# Filter By a ObjectId type field of a Model returning incorrect results in mongoose node js

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema, nosql-aggregation

Schema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const mongoosePaginate = require('mongoose-paginate-v2')
const Schema = mongoose.Schema

const schema = new Schema({
  company: {type:Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Company', required: true},
  brand: {type:Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Brand', required: true},
  reportingDate: Date
})

schema.plugin(mongoosePaginate)

schema.set('toJSON', {
  virtuals: true,
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Domain', schema);
```

query:

```
await db.Domain.find({
   company: req.body.company_id
})
```

or

```
await db.Domain.find({
   company: new require('mongoose').Types.ObjectId(req.body.company_id)
})
```

I am  not getting accurate results from above query. But when i am executing below query i get accurate results

```
await db.Domain.find({
   reportingDate: req.body.reportingDate
})
```

facing problems only filter by those attributes which are of type ObjectId.

Comment: What data type is `req.body.company_id`? If it's not ObjectId, it should never match.

Comment: this is a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

In schema i mentioned **company** an ObjectId but i was saving an string. So i converted company string to ObjectId before saving.

```
let companyId = 'abnsdhdis88qe77qe6e3' // some company id string
let company = new require('mongoose').Types.ObjectId(companyId)
```

and then when i was querying my code is

```
await db.Domain.find({
  company: new require('mongoose').Types.ObjectId(req.body.company_id)
})
```